How to deal with extremely small training dataset in machine learning?
I've around 100 rows of data with labels
Country    |    Category    |   Label
-----------+----------------+----------
[US,UK,JP] |   Electronic   |     1
[US]       |   Sports       |     1
[TW,UK]    |   Grocery      |     2
[JP]       |   Book         |     3

And around 900 rows of data without labels
Country    |    Category   
-----------+--------------
[US,UK]    |   Sports   
[TW]       |   Sports    
[US]       |   Grocery     
[JP]       |   Electronic       

Will it be ok to do classification model using such a small dataset? If so, how can I encode Country? Or is there any other clustering/mathematical approach which I can use to handle this situation?

Naive Bayes is the first thing that you should try

@ThànhNguyễn I'm planning to use one-hot encoding for Category. Any idea how I can encode Country?

Different approaches tend to work better with different sizes of training data. If you want to classify, then a classification model (or a human) tends to be better than some convoluted way of making clustering somehow do classification through the backdoor (esp. when there's little data).
With very little training data, trying to build in as much human knowledge as possible (e.g. into some form of Bayesian model for a categorical or ordinal outcome) and penalization (to avoid overfitting/move things towards reasonable values) can help. Human knowledge here might mean in terms of the structure of the model (such as just using some form of regression model with very few interactions picked by humans up-front), create a really good feature (aka "predictor variable") from understanding what should influence the outcome (e.g. human judgement, existing prediction model, pre-trained embeddings), how similar things should be between different categories (e.g. should category="electronic" behave more or less the same in all countries, or is there some country specific difference, are sports and electronics maybe similar, but very different from groceries; depending on the answer, you can try to encode that in how you do your modeling) or the size of regression coefficients (Bayesian priors and/or penalization). You need to be really careful with basing decisions on data and even tuning hyper-parameters (such as extent of penalization in the various forms it can be implemented) using e.g. cross-validation is dangerous, because you can easily over-fit to the out-of-fold data (see e.g. the "1-standard-error-rule"[-of-thumb] for not overfitting and that's just when you have one hyper-parameter to tune) - maybe nested cross-validation can sometimes help, but needs a lot of thinking to use properly.
In contrast, with very large amounts of data, very data driven approaches often give good prediction performance (e.g. for tabular data gradient boosted trees with extensive hyper-parameter tuning via cross-validation - or with the largest datasets even with just one held-out-fold - neural networks for images/text/audio  etc.).
In wide in-between space, it's a mixture of the two worlds with a lot of space for creativity.
